# Is there a difference between NULL_PEN and PS_NULL?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

```
GetStockObject(NULL_PEN);
CreatePen(PS_NULL, some_width, 0);
```

What's the difference? At the very least, `CreatePen` allows for a width argument, so the widths can be different. Aside from that, are there rendering differences between the two when used to draw?

Comment: We can't meaningfully talk about "rendering differences" with invisible pens.  GetStockObject() is very old, goes back to the days that Windows had to run in 256KB of ram.  Helping apps to shave off bytes, avoiding a call to CreatePen() in this case.  It still works.

Answer (score 4):

NULL_PEN does not need to be destroyed again.

There's some rumor of an optimization of NULL_PEN, but I suspect it's really checking for PS_NULL. Even if not, no difference in the pixels when you're done.

Prefer NULL_PEN to make your life easier.